# How to install Ubuntu on ReiserFS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, reiserfs

I prepared a drive for installing Ubuntu on it and formatted it as ReiserFS using GParted.

But there is no ReiserFS option in the ubuntu installer, so I have to choose a different file system type, but that does not suit me.

How can I still install Ubuntu on ReiserFS?

Best!

Comment: Honestly I do not see serious reason to use unsupported filesystem. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RomeoNinov because that issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/1110122

Comment: Have you try XFS?

Comment: Moreover ServerFault is for managing information technology systems in a business environment. And no one with common sense will use non-supported product on production system.

Comment: @RomeoNinov but the wiki for XFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) says that filename max is 255 bytes too

Comment: I have no problem with XFS, just test it: `touch "/home/romeo/Translations/Ф-119-Д/заключение об аннулировании, исправлении и-или дополнении акта о гражданском состоянии_рум-русс.docx"
[romeo@rhel01 ~]$ ls -l "/home/romeo/Translations/Ф-119-Д/заключение об аннулировании, исправлении и-или дополнении акта о гражданском состоянии_рум-русс.docx"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romeo romeo 0 Sep  7 12:42 '/home/romeo/Translations/Ф-119-Д/заключение об аннулировании, исправлении и-или дополнении акта о гражданском состоянии_рум-русс.docx'`

Comment: hmm.. very strange...

Comment: And will be wise to find a way to shorten the filenames :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have reinstalled Ubuntu using XFS but the error the same.

Comment: My result is from RHEL. But IMHO you do something wrong. Try for example to set LANG to `en_us.UTF8` not `ru_ru.UTF8` for example

Comment: but my result is from Ubuntu-based.
`echo $LANG` -> `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Few point to consider: use relative paths, shorten the filenames/directories, use directory structure to "describe" part of functionality of file, try to remove vowels from words

Comment: @RomeoNinov the error occurs even when I trying to create the file using filename only, without the path. moreover, I can create the file when filename in bytes is 143...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139062/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-nixman).